# Meteor: Import CSS library into CSS file?

Tags: css, meteor, sass, npm, bourbon

I have a meteor 1.3 project. I did:

```
npm i --save bourbon
```

and added

```
@import "bourbon";
```

to my *styles.scss* file.

But I get this error:

```
While processing files with fourseven:scss (for target web.browser):
   /client/styles.scss: Scss compiler error: File to import: {}/client/bourbon not found in file: /Users/olejo/Documents/webapps/myapp/{}/client/styles.scss
```

How do I add a CSS library (in this case; bourbon) into a Meteor CSS file?

(I have added SCSS with `meteor add fourseven:scss`)

Comment: Possibly similar issue on github: https://github.com/wolvesio/meteor-bourbon/issues/11

Comment: Yes, after I found this issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6037#issuecomment-193254586, I ended up with adding Bourbon with `meteor add` instead of `npm`.